# Fails on `docker compose up` when importing .env file in docker-compose.yml

Tags: reactjs, docker-compose

Everything works fine if I remove the following code from `docker-compose.yml`. Though thats not the desired result. Even when I have the `.env` file at the root folder, I get the following error. Tried all but still cannot figure out why thats happening. Any suggestions, as to how to incorporate `.env`.

```
    env_file:
      - .env
```

```
> start
> remix-serve ./build/index.js

[x] http://localhost:3000 (http://172.26.0.2:3000)
/usr/src/x/node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/dist/dev.js:17
if (!origin) throw Error("Dev server origin not set");

Error: Dev server origin not set
```

I have tried following the steps mentioned here `https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#%EF%B8%8F-usage`. Gave up on it and went back to running it via `docker`. Still could not resolve it.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    container_name: x-remix-js
    image: x-remix-js
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - x-cloud-network-front

networks:
  x-cloud-network-back:
    driver: bridge
  x-cloud-network-front:
    driver: bridge
```

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const axiosClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
    withCredentials: false,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    timeout: 5000,
});
```

**.env is under root folder**

Even tried passing as

```
environment:
      - REACT_APP_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8080/something
```

and tried getting the value as `baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL`, still no success